# Drag and Drop in ListView

Tags: qt, listview, drag-and-drop, qml, qt5

I am trying to drag and drop a ListView row and I am having trouble at the drag stage. Below code doesn't drag anything and name column is not aligned properly. I don't want to specify a size for ListView and I want it to get its size from its content `Row` with id row. It should be able to because text has size coming from its font size and Rectangle has set width. ListView can get wider as needed to show the name part.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

ListView {
  id: root
  height: scrollview.viewport.height

  model: listModel
  delegate: dragDelegate

  Component {
    id: dragDelegate

    MouseArea {
      id: dragArea

      anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
      height: content.height

      drag.target: pressed ? content : undefined
      drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis

      Rectangle {
        id: content
        anchors {
          horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
          verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        height: row.implicitHeight

        border.width: 1
        border.color: "lightsteelblue"
        color: "green"
        radius: 2
        states: State {
          when: dragArea.pressed

          ParentChange { target: content; parent: root }
          AnchorChanges {
            target: content
            anchors { horizontalCenter: undefined; verticalCenter: undefined }
          }
        }
        Row {
          id: row

          Text {
            text: name
            font.pointSize: 15
          }
          Rectangle {
            height: parent.height
            width: 40
            color: hexColor
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ListModel {
    id: listModel
    ListElement {
      name: "first-name"
      hexColor: "red"
    }
    ListElement {
      name: "second-name"
      hexColor:  "green"
    }
  }
}
```